# ¿Problema con Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android

Estoy en Android Studio, he creado el Navigation Drawer que viene de serie ya :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentFirst.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FragmentSecond.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();




        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.PRIMERO) {

            fragment = new FragmentFirst();
            FragmentTransaction = true;
        } else if (id == R.id.SEGUNDO) {

            fragment = new FragmentSecond();
            FragmentTransaction = true;


        } else if (id == R.id.TERCERO) {

        } else if (id == R.id.CUARTO) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if(FragmentTransaction) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

y FUNCIONA, pero resulta que si antes de ejecutar este código, pongo una imagen que dure 5 segundos y después inicie esto NO funciona y se me ralla la aplicación, he puesto un botón también como activity para que me lleve al drawer y tampoco.... ¿ Debe estar sí o sí el Navigation Drawer en primer plano ? ¿ No puedo ponerlo como una segunda o tercera Activity?

Fallo que me sale:

> FATAL EXCEPTION:
>
> main
>                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.teleco.espada.teleco/com.teleco.espada.teleco.Presentacion}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
>                                                          at com.teleco.espada.teleco.Presentacion.onCreate(Presentacion.java:28)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  08-10 21:21:52.612
>   1965-2042/? D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService: manageDisableList
>   what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams 08-10 21:21:52.622 1458-1591/?
>   I/SurfaceFlinger: id=140(44) createSurf 0x4033c1cc (1x1),1 flag=4,
>   ueleco 08-10 21:21:52.632 1458-1591/? D/hawaii.hwcomposer:
>   FBDevice::post called 1 times [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 08-10 21:21:52.632
>   1965-2041/? D/CrashAnrDetector: processName: com.teleco.espada.teleco
>   08-10 21:21:52.632 1965-2041/? D/CrashAnrDetector: broadcastEvent :
>   com.teleco.espada.teleco data_app_crash 08-10 21:21:52.642 1458-1790/?
>   E/hawaii.gralloc: GRALLOC ALLOC flags 933 08-10 21:21:52.662
>   1458-1591/? E/HAWAII_EGL: abuffer = (456 199) (933)

Este es el codigo que uso de la imagen principal que se mantiene 4 segundos,

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_presentacion);


            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Presentacion.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }, 4000);


        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que antes de cargar esta Activity, si cargas un imagen el NavigationDrawer no funciona?

Comment: No, yo inicio con una imagen, totalmente independiente al drawer, inicio la aplicación y sale una imagen solamente, centrada en pantalla, y tengo que al cabo de 4 segundos se inicie el drawer, pues cuando pasan esos 4 segundos y se ejecuta el drawer ( lo de arriba expuesto) se ralla y no funciona.

Comment: No entiendo bien a que te refieres con "FUNCIONA, pero resulta que si antes de ejecutar este código, pongo una imagen que dure 5 segundos y después inicie esto NO funciona y se me ralla la aplicación"? (que es ralla?)

Comment: disculpa, ralla me refiero a que la aplicacion se me detiene y deja de funcionar.

Comment: El caso está , que si no pongo lo del navigation drawer al iniciar la aplicación no me va a funcionar y no sé como hacer para colocar una activity antes o un simple xml ...

Comment: ok has visto que se despliega en tu LogCat, el stacktrace que mensaje tiene?

Comment: Lo he actualizado arriba, no sé porque no se pone como codigo,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43770/discussion-between-elenasys-and-rf-mvs).

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error es:

> IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar
>   supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Tu problema es causado porque en la actividad que cargas despues de la primera ya contienes un Toolbar, pero en la primera actividad eliminas la barra del titulo con:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Se supone que no debes modificar la barra si ya tienes un Toolbar, elimina esa linea y  trata nuevamente.